# Asciidoc+a2x to generate HTML output with search capabilities

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor, a2x

I have to use a Asciidoc+a2x solution to generate HTML manuals out of the Asciidoc templates. Is there any opportunity to implement a full-text search into the existing solution (without migrating to an alternative like Sphinx)